# Blank Page after deploying Angular 6 to heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, mean

I've tried deploying my mean app to heroku, Angular 6. The deployment was successful without any errors but the page was blank.

my package.json file is:

```
{
"name": "koko-and-friend",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli typescript @angular-devkit/build-angular"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "primeng": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.2",
    "npm": "6.0.1"
  }
}
```

my server.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/koko-and-friend/index.html'));
 });

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4201, () => {
   console.log('Connected to Port'); //Listening on port 4201
});
```

my angular.json

```
{
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "koko-and-friend": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "sass"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/koko-and-friend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./src/assets/styles/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
             "production": {
                "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
             ],
             "optimization": true,
             "outputHashing": "all",
             "sourceMap": false,
             "extractCss": true,
             "namedChunks": false,
             "aot": true,
             "extractLicenses": true,
             "vendorChunk": false,
             "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
          "browserTarget": "koko-and-friend:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "koko-and-friend:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "koko-and-friend:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.sass"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ]
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
"koko-and-friend-e2e": {
  "root": "e2e/",
  "projectType": "application",
  "architect": {
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "koko-and-friend:serve"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
  },
  "defaultProject": "koko-and-friend"
}
```

When I check the heroku console using bash 'dir', the dist/koko-and-friend folder after the angular app was built is there. This is weird because I'm using this same option for angular 4 exluding the @angular-devkit/build-angular in preinstall. I also checked heroku logs and there's no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace following line in your server.js

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));`

with

`app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/koko-and-friend')));`

Answer (score 1):

Your NPM scripts don't have any logic about moving your content to a specific folder.

This means that your page should be on `dist/index.html`, not `dist/koko-and-friend/index.html`.

Please, also post the content of your `angular-cli.json` (v5) or `angular.json` (v6) file.

Comment: You can see in the angular.json that the path was dist/koko-and-friend/index.html. It was created by the Angular CLI automatically.

Comment: I see that yes. But created automatically ? I doubt so ... Is you dist folder containing this folder ? Also, since you're using a sandbox (Heroku), consider explicitly outputting in your scripts. This means that in your package.json, try this : `"build": "ng build --prod --output-path koko-and-friend"`, and `"postinstall": "npm run build"`

Comment: yes, the path was created automatically after executing this command "ng new koko-and-friend" and when I check the angular.json build path it was like that. Yes, the dist folder contains the koko-and-friend folder which is the name of the app.

Comment: Did you try using explicit outputting ? How did it go ?

Comment: Explicit outputting also did not work with heroku but I fixed it. I modified the automatically created path in Angular.json and instead of using dist/koko-and-friend, I used dist only and moving the whole file to dist folder, removing the koko-and-friend folder. 

I also created a new angular  project with Angular v6 and the build path is really like this "dist/project-name". It was also blank when deployed in heroku and also no errors in logs or deployment so the server can locate the index.html. This is so weird.